# Application threw exception NSInternalInconsistencyException: Invalid parameter not satisfying: pos

Tags: ios

This crash maybe cased by copy and paste. Only iOS 15 has this problem.

CrashDoctor Diagnosis: Application threw exception NSInternalInconsistencyException: Invalid parameter not satisfying: pos

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001814a50fc __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000199ce0d64 objc_exception_throw
2   Foundation                          0x0000000182d5f3ac _userInfoForFileAndLine
3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a4da50 -[_UITextKitTextPosition compare:]
4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001838d4d68 -[UITextInputController comparePosition:toPosition:]
5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a59328 -[UITextView comparePosition:toPosition:]
6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a21658 -[UITextPasteController _clampRange:]
7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a21e4c __87-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]_block_invoke
8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a22064 __87-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]_block_invoke.177
9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a49b9c -[UITextInputController _pasteAttributedString:toRange:completion:]
10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a21d94 -[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]
11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a21030 __49-[UITextPasteController _executePasteForSession:]_block_invoke
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000181115924 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000181117670 _dispatch_client_callout
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000181125b70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018145dd84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181417f5c __CFRunLoopRun
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018142b468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000019cfb738c GSEventRunModal
19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183dcd088 -[UIApplication _run]
20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183b4b958 UIApplicationMain
21  GalaxyX                             0x0000000102f2d67c main + [main.m : 19]
```

Comment: Please review [ask].

Comment: The crash log is all information I have got. Maybe this is a system crash.

Comment: This crash maybe cased by copy and paste.